# How to move an object in relationship to a specific vertex numerically?

Tags: coordinates

I am coming from a "2d-world" like Adobe Illustrator where I easily could move objects in relationship with their "corners" numerically. How do I do this in Blender? Let me explain:
[image]

I have object 01 that I want to move beside object 02. I want the topright corner (vertex 01V2) to be EXACTLY where the vertex 02V3 is for object O2. I don't want to use snap, but move O1 numerically. I first want to KNOW what the coordinates for O2V3 are. Then I want to move object O1 to those coordinates.
[image]

How do I do this? It seems like something very basic to me, but I have looked for the solution "all over the place" but can't find it. Thanks a lot in advance!

BTW-And when I have this answer I would also like to apply the same principle to transforms like size and so on... ;-)

Comment: May I ask why you don't want to use snap?

Comment: "May I ask why you don't want to use snap?"

I don't feel in control of what is happening, and when there are multiple objects in the vicinity, I don't know if the snap is correct. Numerical positioning gets rid of that uncertainty.

Comment: Well, snapping can be tricky sometimes but as many other tools it has some different settings. When I started with Blender I always thought snapping is kind of doing what it wants, but that was when I was just using the default settings which were not always appropriate to what I wanted to achieve. Nowadays I use it way more often - of course numerical positioning can be more accurate, when you know the numbers you need ;) Usually I use a combination of both. Snapping to a certain point, then moving from there by entering values for translation.

Answer (score 0):

As 3D world is more complicated than 2D, the procedures can be less easy, but they become fast as you get used to them.

Using vertex snapping is the fastest way to get the desired result, but if you really want to use numbers, here is a procedure you can follow, which basically adds to the X loc of your object O1 the expression (`O2V3.x - O1V2.x`).

Open two different 3D windows, one with the standard *Transform* tab in the  <kbd>N</kbd> properties side panel, one with the *View > 3D cursor* tab.

- Change the snapping mode to *Vertex*, but don't turn it on, leave it off.
- Press and hold <kbd>⇧ Shift</kbd> and click and move <kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd> to move the 3D cursor around. When close to your `01V2` vertex press the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> or <kbd>Cmd</kbd> key also, to snap the 3D cursor to the vertex.
- click on the *X* coordinates of the 3D cursor in the view tab and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>C</kbd> to copy it.
- click on the x coordinate of your object 01, click again to deselect its original value and press <kbd>-</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>, to subtract the 3D `cursor.x` value from original `transform.x` value.
- repeat for your `O2V3` vertex, but this time add its X loc value to the expression of the `O1.x` value
- if needed repeat everything for *Y* values

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your input. I will try it out!